# how to implement Exif.PCL in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, exif

I am trying to create a project in which picture is taken to upload from mobile camera, but when it is taken with front camera it rotates upside down (especially Android). I have read suggestions to use Exif.PCL nuget package but dont know how to implement the same. Can anybody help me out with this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

I had the same problem in one of my apps. After trying different approaches I've found several problems with current implementations. Generally I use [XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs), which has media picking capabilities.

**Issues**

First of all it lacked support for scaling and autorotating images after they are taken. That's your question. So, first of all I had to implement some after-processing as soon as the image was picked.

Second, there are problems with Android and Xamarin.Forms due do how Activities are handled in Android. The way it works on Android is you launch CameraActivity or PhotoGalleryActivity which are actually hosted in a different application. Those Activities use substential amount of system memory, and due to this operating system will try to kill non-forground processes, including your app :) Workarround for this was completely implementing photo taking flow inside of my application by creating photo taking activities from scratch. Thus, I will never leave my app, and Android runtime will never kill my application.

**Solution**

Taking account all of this, I've implement my own flow of Image capturing. You can find the source code [HERE](https://github.com/kyurkchyan/xamarin-samples/tree/master/ImageSample). The basic architecture is following:
I've created `IImageService`, which has methods for picking images from camera or library.

```
public interface IImageService
    {
        Task<IImage> GetImageFromLibrary();
        Task<IImage> GetImageFromCamera();
    }
```

Then I've implemented this for iOS and Android separately and used dependency injection. For iOS I use XLabs implementation, cause it works as it should there are no problems with it. For Android I've created several activities to support picking images from Camera and Library: `CameraActivity`, `PhotoGaleryActivity`, which basically replace the native image picking activities.

After I pick the image I do scaling and rotating procedure. For iOS I've created `UIImageToolbox` static class which has `GetScaledAndRotatedImage` method. For Android it's `BitmapToolbox` static class which has `GetScaledAndRotatedBitmap` method.

In my sample application I've created `ImageViewModel` and `ImagePage` to demonstrate the usage of `IImageService`. It should be straightforward.

**How to use the sample app?**

Let me give a small remark. You can use only XLabs implementation for both iOS and Android and just use `BitmapToolbox` and `UIImageToolbox` to implement the scaling and rotation. And this is answer to your question. However, if you want your app to be stable on Android you need to go a little bit dipper.

1. Install all the necessary nuget packages to your Forms, Droid and iOS projects. You can find the packages that are used by sample application in `packages.config` file of each project
2. I use [MvvmCross Messenger](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger) plugin for broadcast messaging, if you have alternative you can easily replace it. But if you want to use it, don't forget to register dependencies in your `AppDelegate` and `MainActivity`

   DependencyService.Register();
3. Add necessary classes to your Forms, iOS and Android projects from sample application. You can use Resharper to fix namespaces for you.
4. For xaml files, if you drug and drop to forms project default build action and Custom Tool are set to wrong values. Thus click the xaml file, select properties set Build Action to *Embedded Resource*, and Custom Tool to *MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml*
5. For android project add necessary resources from `drawable`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, `layout` and `values` folders.
6. In grid_cell_photo_galery_item.axml file fix namespaces. Replace `ImageSample.Droid.Views.SquareRelativeLayout` by your namespace.
7. For Android, right click Android project, select properties, go to Android Manifest and add CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.
8. For Android, right click Android project, select properties, go to Advanced and set Max Heap Size to something like 1G, this is needed because PhotoGalaryActivity uses substantial amount of memory to display images and we need an increased heap size.
9. For iOS, don't forget to add dependency injection for `MediaPicker` in `AppDelegate` - `DependencyService.Register<MediaPicker>();`

That's all.